# В чем причина возникновения Array required but int found?

Tags: java

На всякий случай прикрепил весь код, чтобы точно не было вырвано из контекста.

Метод get возвращает i-ый элемент из массива, который записан в список а под номером k. Return в теле метода get выдает данную ошибку.

Понимаю, что что-то неправильно, но конкретно корень ошибки выявить не могу

Буду благодарен за любой совет или подсказку

Прошу прощения, код не захотел корректно вставляться, а я здесь совсем новичок

```
public class Main implements Cloneable {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<int[]> a = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 

        int n;
        for( ; ; ) 
        {
            n = reader.nextInt(); 
            if(n<100000) break;            
        }      
        int[] a0 = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a0[i] = reader.nextInt();
        a.add(a0);
        int m;
        for( ; ; )
        {
            m = reader.nextInt(); 
            if(m<100000) break;            
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < m+1; i++){
            String request = reader.nextLine();

        if (request=="create") 
        {

            int version = reader.nextInt();
            int position = reader.nextInt(); 
            int symbol = reader.nextInt();

            create(a, position, version, symbol);

        } 
        else
        if (request=="get")   
        {

            int version = reader.nextInt();
            int position = reader.nextInt();

            System.out.println(get(a, position, version));

        }  
    }   
}

   public static void create(List<int[]> a, int position, int version, int symbol)
   {

          a.add((a.get(version)).clone());
          int last=a.size();
          a.get(last)[position]=symbol;

      }

    public static int get(List<int[]> a, int position, int version)
    {

          return a.get((version)[position]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вставляете код, выделяете его целиком, жмете на кнопку с `{}`, скрипт вставит в каждую строку отступ в 4 пробела (или уберет, если все строки начинаются с такого отступа).

Comment: по вопросу - надо `a.get(version)[position]`, т.к. `get` вернет массив, лежащий в списке.

Comment: [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в методе `get()`. Правильно так:

```
public static int get(List<int[]> a, int position, int version)
        {

              return a.get(version)[position];
        }
```